# How to access objects from array of data in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following hook

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function FetchData(url) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setData(data));
    }, []);

    return data;
}
```

I called this hook by writing the following code

```
const data = FetchData("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search");
```

The previous API return the result with "hits" not directly in data

The problem was when I write the following code :

```
return (
          data.hits.map(hit =>
                    <div>{hit.title}</div>
                )

              );
```

I know that I can solve this problem by add "hits" in the hook , but I don't want to do this because I need the hook to be general . 
I need to manipulate the data in the calling part not in the hook . 
to be more specific , how can I access the hits data from the calling context not from the hook .

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
 return (
           data && data.hits && data.hits.map(hit => <div>{hit.title}</div>)
         );
```

Comment: Yes. if data is empty,this code doesn't crash.Once data are coming,this code will work.

Comment: Your details not sufficient. Give more details to solve this problem. Also post API response structure